# automate dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

Tags: debian, puppet, timezone, dpkg, debconf

I'm using puppet to admin a cluster of debian servers.  I need to change the timezone of each machine on the cluster.  The proper debian way to do this is to use `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`. But I can only seem to change it if I use the dialog.  Is there some way to automate this from the shell so I can just write an Exec to make this easy?

If not, I think the next best way would probably be to have puppet distribute `/etc/timezone` and `/etc/localtime` with the correct data across the cluster.

Any input appreciated!

Comment: Note that the currently accepted answer has been wrong [since 2017](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/1554806/comments/9). The correct answer is [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/84521/automate-dpkg-reconfigure-tzdata/846989#846989).

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You need to specify the frontend as `noninteractive' and it will save your current settings.

dpkg-reconfigure will take the current system settings as gospel, so simply change your timezone the way you would normally and run it with the non-interactive flag

e.g. for me to change to "Europe/Dublin" where I am:

```
# echo "Europe/Dublin" > /etc/timezone    
# dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

Obviously this allows you to use puppet/cfengine as you like to distribute /etc/timezone also.

#### EDIT:

after @gertvdijk comment pointing to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/1554806 and @scruss [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/846989/564567) you will probably have to do it like this in most modern distributions:

```
$ sudo ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Dublin /etc/localtime
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

Comment: as an alternative to changing permissions, you could do something like this.

`echo 'Europe/Dublin' | sudo tee /etc/timezone > /dev/null`

Comment: For completeness, another way to echo via sudo is `sudo bash -c 'echo "Europe/Dublin" > /etc/timezone'`

Comment: Heads up! Newer Ubuntu/Debian versions don't work this way anymore. Behaviour changed. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/1554806

Answer (score 38):

Since the [accepted answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/84521/automate-dpkg-reconfigure-tzdata/84528#84528) no longer works (Debian Jessie, April 2017), an approach modified from @gertvdijk's [comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/84521/automate-dpkg-reconfigure-tzdata/84528#comment1017649_84528) link appears to do the job now:

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Dublin /etc/localtime
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use [debconf-set-selections](http://man.he.net/man1/debconf-set-selections) to preset the configuration.  Install debconf-utils and run `debconf-get-selections | grep tzdata` on a properly configured system to figure out what to set it too.

Comment: For things that are debconf based, this should work. But tzdata prefers the config from /etc/timezone. So this does not work on an already installed (wheezy) system.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the recipe from the (now defunct) [Puppet wiki](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Timezone_Patterns) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160517211817/http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Timezone_Patterns)) which replaces `/etc/localtime` with the appropriate zoneinfo file from `/usr/share/zoneinfo`:-

```
class timezone {
    package { "tzdata":
        ensure => installed
    }
}

class timezone::central inherits timezone {
    file { "/etc/localtime":
        require => Package["tzdata"],
        source => "file:///usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central",
    }
}

class timezone::eastern inherits timezone {
    file { "/etc/localtime":
        require => Package["tzdata"],
        source => "file:///usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Eastern"
    }
}

class timezone::pacific inherits timezone {
    file { "/etc/localtime":
        require => Package["tzdata"],
        source => "file:///usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific"
    }
}

class timezone::mountain inherits timezone {
    file { "/etc/localtime":
        require => Package["tzdata"],
        source =>
             "file:///usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Mountain"
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if dpkg-reconfigure does anything extra, but I have used the above recipe and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo EDITOR='sed -Ei "
    s|tzdata/Areas=.+|tzdata/Areas=\"Asia\"|;
    s|tzdata/Zones/Asia=.+|tzdata/Zones/Asia=\"Shanghai\"|
    "' dpkg-reconfigure -f editor tzdata
```

Related answer: [How do you set a locale non-interactively on Debian/Ubuntu?](https://serverfault.com/a/1114285)

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive` not very intuitive.

I want to point out another way.

### A. debconf frontend: teletype

It's a hidden option (seems debconf builtin frontend).

```bash
echo -e 'Asia\nTokyo' | sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata -f teletype
```

It's easy to read and write.

#### debconf frontends

see all frontends (but no `teletype` listed)

`dpkg-reconfigure debconf`
or
`dpkg-reconfigure debconf -f teletype`

1. Dialog
2. Readline
3. Gnome
4. Kde
5. Editor
6. Noninteractive

#### check timezone

```
$ ll /etc/localtime; tail -v /etc/timezone
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Apr 30 02:59 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo
==> /etc/timezone <==
Asia/Tokyo
```

NOTE: sometimes maybe you need `rm /etc/localtime` first (if it is broken link).

### B. manually edit file

maybe off-topic

```bash
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime
echo 'Asia/Tokyo' > /etc/timezone
```

OR

```bash
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime
apt install tzdata        # it will use the linked timezone
```

OR

```bash
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata   # it will use the linked timezone
```

---

tested on ubuntu18 & 20

Answer (score -5):

Its very simple and only need to type a command and answer the simple questions.
then run:

```
/usr/bin/tzselect
```

Comment: man tzselect: "Note that tzselect will not actually change the timezone for you. Use 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' to achieve this."