# Setting the Timezone with an automated script

Tags: linux, debian, bash, scripting, timezone

I'm writing scripts to automate setting up new slicehost installations.  In a perfect world, after I started the script, it would just run, with no attention from me.  I have succeeded, with one exception.

How do I set the timezone, in a permanent (survive reboot) and sane (adjust for standard and daylight savings time, so no just forcing the date) ... manner that doesn't require input from me?

Currently, I'm using

```
 dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

This doesn't seem to have any way to force parameters into it.  It demands user input.

---

EDIT:  I'm editing here, rather than commenting, since comments don't seem to allow code blocks.

Here's the actual code I ended up with, based on Rudedog's comment below.  I also noticed that this doesn't update /etc/timezone.  I'm not certain who uses that, but in case anybody does, I'm setting that too.

```
TIMEZONE="America/Los_Angeles"      
echo $TIMEZONE > /etc/timezone                     
cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TIMEZONE} /etc/localtime   # This sets the time
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to do this with

```
cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
```

Substitute the appropriate timezone in the above command.

Comment: you should be symlinking that not copying over

Comment: He's using Debian. `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` makes a copy, not a symlink. I believe the rationale is because /usr/share might not be mounted at boot time.

Comment: According to the technical section of the tzconfig manpage for Debian:

>The work done by tzconfig is actually pretty simple. It just updates the link /etc/localtime to point to the correct timezone installed in /usr/share/zoneinfo/.

Comment: tzconfig is deprecated on lenny in favor of dpkg-reconfigure tzdata and won't actually do anything. You can verify that it copies instead of symlinks by running dpkg-reconfigure tzdata and look at the result.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 12.04 the following did the trick for me:

```
# http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man7/debconf.7.html
export DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
echo "Europe/Berlin" > /etc/timezone
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Comment: This method doesn't appear to work anymore https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/1554806

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
echo "Europe/London" > /etc/timezone
dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.

Comment: This method doesn't appear to work anymore https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/1554806

Answer (score 2):

Update `/etc/localtime` symlink to point to correct timezone in `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$(tzselect) /etc/localtime
```

Comment: Note that if you use a symlink and your `/usr` is mounted on a separate partition, anything that starts before `/usr` gets mounted will not have the correct timezone. Most distros today, including Debian, copy rather than symlink.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this myself. Here's a complete config for how to do this right (it's an aggregate of comments in here and [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/84521/automate-dpkg-reconfigure-tzdata)):

```
#Set time zone and time
echo "tzdata tzdata/Areas select Europe" | debconf-set-selections
echo "tzdata tzdata/Zones/Europe select London" | debconf-set-selections
TIMEZONE="Europe/London"
echo $TIMEZONE > /etc/timezone
cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TIMEZONE} /etc/localtime
/usr/sbin/ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

Answer (score 0):

`tzdata` uses debconf to answer that question, so you need to prepopulate it. There's several ways to do this, the easiest is to [preseed the answer during installation](http://d-i.alioth.debian.org/manual/en.i386/apbs04.html#preseed-time). Beyond that you can set up a default database for debconf to use, see the `debconf(7)` manpage for how do that.

Answer (score -2):

Also make sure that ntpd is installed and running.

```
yum install ntpd
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
service ntpd start
```