# debconf ssh install variable names

Tags: debian, debconf

I am writing a bash shell script that sets up a server. To prevent it asking for e.g. the mysql server root password I use

```
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password roooot'
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password roooot'
```

and of course I use the `-y` parameter for `apt-get install`.

Now when installing ssh on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS it asks me whether to disable the SSH password authentication for root. I want to define an answer for that, too.

So: What is that question's name? And in more general: How can I find out those parameters by myself?

```
debconf-set-selections <<< 'ssh ?? boolean true/false'
```

Comment: Use debconf-get-selections on a working system.  http://serverfault.com/questions/84521/automate-dpkg-reconfigure-tzdata/84529#84529

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Zoredache, `debconf-get-selections` on a machine where this version of ssh is already installed did it.

The command in this case is:

```
debconf-set-selections <<< 'openssh-server openssh-server/permit-root-login boolean true'
```